# Apache AuthLDAPBindDN directive accepting any field?

Tags: apache, ldap

Regarding LDAP authentication in Apache http server, I wonder why providing just one ***sAMAccountName*** or ***userPrincipalName*** to the `AuthLDAPBindDN` directive, instead of giving the user's full ***dn*** is also working.

The documentation states you must provide a ***DN*** as the argument to this directive, but I've tried to provide just a ***sAMAccountName***, and it works. Providing ***userPrincipalName*** also works. I'm quite confused. Why is it working?

Is it because I'm connecting to an AD server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Active Directory implements a system called [Ambiguous Name Resolution (ANR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_name_resolution) which allows resolution of the user to permit an LDAP Bind.